# How to put different count queries in one table result

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

If I have these three count queries, for ex:

First:

```
Select count(*)   as red
from A 

result = 10
```

Second:

```
Select count(*)   as yellow
from B

result = 15
```

Third:

```
Select count (*)  as green
from C

result = 20
```

how can I make the result using oracle to be like

```
red      yellow      green
10         15          20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select (Select count(*) from a) red, (Select count(*) from b) yellow, (Select count(*) from b) green from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this :

```
select * from (Select count(*) as red from A) as count_A
 ,(Select count(*)   as yellow from B) as count_B
 ,(Select count (*)  as green from C) as count_C
```